# Keyboard arrow keys navigation with Easy Slider 1.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, slideshow

I'm trying to edit the [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) to allow the keyboard's arrow keys to navigate the slideshow.

I tried editing the [javascript's](http://stanford.edu/group/webdev/champions/js/easy-slider.js) animate function from:

```
default:
t = dir;
break;
```

...to:

```
default:
t = parseInt(dir);
break;
```

...but that didn't work.

Does anyone know how to use the keyboard's arrow keys to navigate this slideshow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your next and prev links have IDs of #next and #prev:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       $('a#next').trigger('click');
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
         $('a#prev').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

I'm also not familiar with easy slider, but if they have a way to programmatically switch the slides back and forth, then you could swap out the triggers with those. The posted solution will work fine though.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added your code in my head tag and I can't seem to get it working. The only editing I did was to match the ids, which are prevId & nextId. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: I also tried adding your code to the default Easy Slider here: http://bit.ly/m5KJjC - I tried editing the IDs to 'span#nextId', 'span#nextBtn', 'span#nextBtn a', with no luck.