# jquery to click through images in a div

Tags: jquery

How can i add button control (next and previous) to click through and display images listed in a div with jquery?  Right now i have a big image

```
<img src="/image.php?height=372&image=/slideShow/1302813283.jpg" id="lgImage">
```

a div for captions

```
<div id="thecap">

</div>
```

and a div of thumbnails

```
<div id="thumbs">
<div id="slideShow"><!--start slideShow-->
<a rel="images/image1.jpg"><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="Text For Image 1" width="50" height="50" title="something" rel="images/image1.jpg">
<div style="display:none;">
<strong>Header</strong> <br><br>lsfjas;ld jaslj ljs f;lkajsd ;fkjas ;dfja;sdklf a;sljfa;lsdkjf a;sdklfj a;lskdfja;sklfj a;lksdfj a;klsfj a;klsfj a;lskfj a;lsfj
</div>
</a>
<a rel="images/image2.jpg"><img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="Text For Image 2" width="50" height="50" title="something" rel="images/image2.jpg">
<div style="display:none;">
<strong>Header</strong> <br><br>lsfjas;ld jaslj ljs f;lkajsd ;fkjas ;dfja;sdklf a;sljfa;lsdkjf a;sdklfj a;lskdfja;sklfj a;lksdfj a;klsfj a;klsfj a;lskfj a;lsfj
</div>

</a>
<a rel="images/image3.jpg"><img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="Text For Image 3" width="50" height="50" title="something" rel="images/image3.jpg">
<div style="display:none;">
<strong>Header</strong> <br><br>lsfjas;ld jaslj ljs f;lkajsd ;fkjas ;dfja;sdklf a;sljfa;lsdkjf a;sdklfj a;lskdfja;sklfj a;lksdfj a;klsfj a;klsfj a;lskfj a;lsfj
</div>
</a>
<a rel="images/image4.jpg"><img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="Text For Image 4" width="50" height="50" title="something" rel="images/image4.jpg">
<div style="display:none;">
<strong>Header</strong> <br><br>lsfjas;ld jaslj ljs f;lkajsd ;fkjas ;dfja;sdklf a;sljfa;lsdkjf a;sdklfj a;lskdfja;sklfj a;lksdfj a;klsfj a;klsfj a;lskfj a;lsfj
</div>
</a>
<!--end slideShow-->
</div>
</div>
```

and here is my jquery so far.

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#slideShow a").click(function() {
    var imgTitle = $(this).children('div').html(); // Find the image title
    $("#thecap").html(' ' + imgTitle + ' ');


    $("#lgImage").attr('src', $(this).children('img').attr('rel'));
    $("#lgImage").css("display","none");
    $("#lgImage").fadeIn(1500);

    $("#thecap").css("display","none");
    $("#thecap").fadeIn(1500);

    });
```

if i click a thumbnail the big image changes and so does the caption.  I want to add a left and right arrow button control to click through (next or previous) with jquery.  Any Thoughts?

Comment: see the jquery inplug
http://www.slidesjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

u can use this [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) jquery plugin but i don't know this plugin will help. u can go previous image and going next image. also it shows images in dialog window.

Comment: fancybox is good but not what i am looking for.  i want to click through so it updates the big image like clicking the thumbs but using next and previous controls

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous slider plugins that you can use such as this: 
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

Implementing keyboard navigation is easy: [Keyboard arrow keys navigation with Easy Slider 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221591/keyboard-arrow-keys-navigation-with-easy-slider-1-7)
This one supports it out of the box: http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/

You can include captions in the 'sliding' `div` along with the image.

Comment: a slider would be good but i need to be able to have both thumb control and arrow control as well as caption but i need to be able to specify where the captions go.  in a div away from the big image

Comment: See my updated answer. Do you need to have a single div for captions?

Comment: yes, single div where the captions will display.  right now a div within each <a> to hold the caption for each image

Comment: Managing with a single `div` will be more tricky (not impossible, but difficult). Unless absolutely required for some reason, I would suggest to stay with individual `divs`.